# How can I pass value from jsx/redux/mongoDB to a js function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, react-redux

I have a problem with passing data from redux/jsx to a js function. Basically my MERN app works like: You have to log in to do something(turn on/off buttons). While you log in you have assigned to your account role with different permissions. My problem accords to the role. I can put it out from the 'redux' as

```
 {user.role}
```

and it gives me the role. The thing is I need to use it in js function which firstly check if user isAuthenticated then checks his role. So as you all know I can't simply use:

```
 function isRole({user.role}) {
if ({user.role}) {
...};}
```

Because console gives me an error about "user.role in a function, expected a comma instead of a dot".
How can I do that to make it work? 
I tried to use the standalone { role } but  then it says its not defined.

Comment: can you please post a full code snippet of your Component ?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/ebdfddfce1515a65d4888fe11db3fecb
https://gyazo.com/fb41e04521a1546b778bbdb53091bd97
https://gyazo.com/96fd06a5b02cc08667707f2dce992dab

Comment: When declaring the function isRole you dont need to use brackets. 
function isRole(userRole) {if (userRole){.....}};
Once you invoke the function, you can pass the userRole argument using isRole({user.role});

Comment: It looks like you tried to declare the function and invoke it at the same time.

Comment: What you mean? I mean I commented the function to not make the app crash for now but if I will delete the comment It will say that 'role' is not defined. If i will change it to { user.role } then it will say about there should be a comma instead of a dot

Comment: Ahh okay, I didnt see your first comment. I will try it asap and tell you if it works, thank you <3

Comment: You are invoking checkRole like this: checkRole({role}) inside toggleImage function
It tries to create an object from role variable. this variable is not defined - this causes the undefined error
When you are switching to {user.role} in the function declaration, you have a syntax error. you cannot declare a function argument like that.
To fix this issue you need to declare a role variable or to change you function in a way that the role will be passed to the function.

Comment: @dimagolovin I did what you said and Ive created a function isRole (userRole) { .... } but it says that userRole is not defined :/

Comment: can you post the code as you changed it?

Comment: @dimagolovin Yes, sure. Here it is: 
https://gyazo.com/a584a3f1a5e9c2dba0abd1a3974c2440
Ive tried with ({ user.role}) as an argument while trying to call the function but it was the same.

Comment: userRole is not define inside toogleImage function. You need to pass a valid value to the function (I dont know if you are getting your User object from state or from props but it has to be one way or another, state is the appropriate one).

Comment: @dimagolovin I did solve this, thanks for help <3